# Write permission for wpengine file

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, chmod

I want to set write permission for .php file in wordpress file hosted on wpengine host. Can you please provide me permission required to write file in this.

Answer (score 0):

WP Engine pushes out a default set of file permissions for content uploaded via sFTP. You can reset default perms from your WPE plugin in the WP-ADMIN area.
Open the plugin, scroll down and hit `Reset Permissions`.